# Make RelativeLayout moveable in Android

Tags: android, android-layout

I have found this piece of Code for making `ImageView` moveable.

```
final int X = (int) event.getRawX();
            final int Y = (int) event.getRawY();
            //Definition MotionEvent.ACTION_MASK: Bit mask of the parts of the action code that are the action itself.
            switch (event.getAction() & MotionEvent.ACTION_MASK) {
                case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
                    RelativeLayout.LayoutParams lParams = (RelativeLayout.LayoutParams) view.getLayoutParams();
                    _xDelta = X - lParams.leftMargin;
                    _yDelta = Y - lParams.topMargin;
                    break;
                case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
                    break;
                case MotionEvent.ACTION_POINTER_DOWN:
                    break;
                case MotionEvent.ACTION_POINTER_UP:
                    break;
                case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:
                    RelativeLayout.LayoutParams layoutParams = (RelativeLayout.LayoutParams) view
                            .getLayoutParams();

                    layoutParams.leftMargin = X - _xDelta;
                    layoutParams.topMargin = Y - _yDelta;
                    layoutParams.rightMargin = -250;
                    layoutParams.bottomMargin = -250;
                    view.setLayoutParams(layoutParams);
                    break;

            }
            root.invalidate();

            break;
```

Now I want to add this Code for a `RelativeLayout`.
For that case I put a `RelativeLayout` into another `RelativeLayout` like:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"

android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:id="@+id/test">

<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:id="@+id/root">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/skizze"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:scaleType="matrix" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/feuerloescherID"
        android:layout_width="55dp"
        android:layout_height="55dp"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="false"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal|top" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

This is the Code but not for my `ImageView` but for `RelativeLayout`.

```
final int rootX = (int) event.getRawX();
            final int rootY = (int) event.getRawY();
            switch (event.getAction() & MotionEvent.ACTION_MASK) {
                case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN: //first finger down only
                    RelativeLayout.LayoutParams layoutParams = (RelativeLayout.LayoutParams) view.getLayoutParams();
                    int left = layoutParams.leftMargin;
                    int top = layoutParams.topMargin;
                    _xDelta = rootX - layoutParams.leftMargin;
                    _yDelta = rootY - layoutParams.topMargin;
                    break;
                case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP://first finger lifted
                break;
                case MotionEvent.ACTION_POINTER_UP: //second finger lifted
                    break;
                case MotionEvent.ACTION_POINTER_DOWN: //first and second finger down
                    break;
                case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:
                    RelativeLayout.LayoutParams layoutParams1 = (RelativeLayout.LayoutParams) view.getLayoutParams();
                    layoutParams1.leftMargin = rootX - _xDelta;
                    layoutParams1.topMargin = rootY - _yDelta;
                    layoutParams1.rightMargin = -250;
                    layoutParams1.bottomMargin = -250;
                    view.setLayoutParams(layoutParams1);
                    break;
            }
            root.invalidate();
```

So I can use the same Code again.
My Problem is, that I can't move the Layout around the Screen. It is "docked" in the bottom right corner of the screen.
If I move the Layout, it's got to get stretched insteaf of moved.

What is wrong?

Comment: I create a touch moving object layou yesterday night, anything that inside the layout can be moved. I really want to share my code to you, it is very simple. But i don't have the code now, because the code is in my personal computer, i am at work now.

Comment: That Sounds really good! Is the Layout itselves moveable too or just the objects in it?

Comment: the concept is very simple, i create a findViewByPosition function. you touch the layout, you will use this function to find if there is a child view at the touched position, if there is, you just set the child view's x and y by view.setX(i), setY(i) when your finger is moving.

Comment: the objects in the layout.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

it is me, this is my code

this is the object moving layout
anything inside this layout can be moved.

```
/**
 * Created by DennyShum on 10/7/15.
 */
public class TouchMovingLayout extends RelativeLayout implements View.OnTouchListener{

    public static interface OnChildViewClickListener{
        public void onChildViewClick(View view);
        public void onChildViewLongClick(View view);
    }


    private OnChildViewClickListener onChildViewClickListener;
    private GestureDetector gestureDetector;
    private ImageView recyclerIcon;
    private View touchedView;
    float xOffset = 0;
    float yOffset = 0;

    public TouchMovingLayout(Context context) {
        this(context, null);
    }

    public TouchMovingLayout(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        this(context, attrs, 0);
    }

    public TouchMovingLayout(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyleAttr) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyleAttr);

        recyclerIcon = new ImageView(getContext());
        LayoutParams params = new LayoutParams
                (LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
        params.addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_PARENT_BOTTOM);
        params.addRule(RelativeLayout.CENTER_HORIZONTAL);
        params.bottomMargin = (int)(getContext().getResources().getDisplayMetrics().density * 24.0f);
        recyclerIcon.setLayoutParams(params);
        recyclerIcon.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_delete_white_36dp);
        recyclerIcon.setVisibility(INVISIBLE);
        addView(recyclerIcon);

        gestureDetector = new GestureDetector(getContext(), gestureListener);
        gestureDetector.setIsLongpressEnabled(true);

        setClickable(true);
        setOnTouchListener(this);
    }

    public void setOnChildViewClickListener(OnChildViewClickListener onChildViewClickListener){
        this.onChildViewClickListener = onChildViewClickListener;
    }

    private boolean shouldDeleteElement(View elementView){

        float bottom = elementView.getY() + elementView.getHeight();
        float left = elementView.getX();
        float startSpot = recyclerIcon.getX() -  elementView.getWidth();
        float endSpot = recyclerIcon.getX() + recyclerIcon.getWidth();

        if (bottom > recyclerIcon.getY() && (left > startSpot && left < endSpot)){
            return true;
        }else{
            return false;
        }
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onTouch(View view, MotionEvent motionEvent) {

        if (motionEvent.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN){

            touchedView = ViewUtil.findViewByPosition
                    (this, motionEvent.getX(), motionEvent.getY());

            if (touchedView != null){

                if (touchedView == recyclerIcon){
                    touchedView = null;
                    return false;
                }

                xOffset = motionEvent.getX() - touchedView.getX();
                yOffset = motionEvent.getY() - touchedView.getY();
                //touchedView.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.rectangle_background_white_black_das);
                recyclerIcon.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            }
        }

        if (motionEvent.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_UP){
            if (touchedView != null){
                touchedView.setBackgroundColor(Color.TRANSPARENT);

                if (shouldDeleteElement(touchedView)){
                    removeView(touchedView);
                }

                touchedView = null;
            }

            recyclerIcon.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
        }

        if (touchedView != null){
            touchedView.setX(motionEvent.getX() - xOffset);
            touchedView.setY(motionEvent.getY() - yOffset);

            if (shouldDeleteElement(touchedView)){
                //recyclerIcon.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.rectangle_background_white_black_das);
                recyclerIcon.getDrawable().setColorFilter(Color.RED, PorterDuff.Mode.MULTIPLY);
            }else{
                recyclerIcon.setBackgroundColor(Color.TRANSPARENT);
                recyclerIcon.getDrawable().clearColorFilter();
            }
        }

        gestureDetector.onTouchEvent(motionEvent);
        return false;
    }


    private GestureDetector.OnGestureListener gestureListener =
            new GestureDetector.OnGestureListener() {

        @Override
        public boolean onDown(MotionEvent motionEvent) {
            return false;
        }

        @Override
        public void onShowPress(MotionEvent motionEvent) {

        }

        @Override
        public boolean onSingleTapUp(MotionEvent motionEvent) {
            if (onChildViewClickListener != null){

                onChildViewClickListener.onChildViewClick(
                        ViewUtil.findViewByPosition(TouchMovingLayout.this,
                                motionEvent.getX(), motionEvent.getY())
                );
            }
            return false;
        }

        @Override
        public boolean onScroll(MotionEvent motionEvent, MotionEvent motionEvent1, float v, float v1) {
            return false;
        }

        @Override
        public void onLongPress(MotionEvent motionEvent) {
            if (onChildViewClickListener != null){

                onChildViewClickListener.onChildViewLongClick(
                        ViewUtil.findViewByPosition(TouchMovingLayout.this,
                                motionEvent.getX(), motionEvent.getY())
                );
            }
        }

        @Override
        public boolean onFling(MotionEvent motionEvent, MotionEvent motionEvent1, float v, float v1) {
            return false;
        }
    };

    @Override
    protected void onMeasure(int widthMeasureSpec, int heightMeasureSpec) {
        super.onMeasure(widthMeasureSpec, heightMeasureSpec);
    }
}
```

This is the find findViewByPosition utility

```
/**
 * Created by DennyShum on 10/7/15.
 */
public class ViewUtil {

    public static View findViewByPosition(ViewGroup parentView, float x, float y){

        if (parentView == null) return null;
        if (parentView.getWidth() == 0 || parentView.getHeight() == 0) return null;

        for (int i = parentView.getChildCount() - 1; i > -1 ; i--){
            View view = parentView.getChildAt(i);
            if (view.getWidth() == 0 || view.getHeight() ==0) continue;

            float top = view.getY();
            float bottom = top + view.getHeight();
            float left = view.getX();
            float right = left + view.getWidth();

            if ((y >= top && y <= bottom) && (x >= left && x <= right)){
                return view;
            }

        }

        return null;
    }

}
```

xml implement code

```
<com.pompeiicity.smslibrary.widgets.TouchMovingLayout
        android:id="@+id/floatElementHolder"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <View
            android:layout_width="80dp"
            android:layout_height="80dp"
            android:background="@color/someColor"/>

        <View
            android:layout_width="80dp"
            android:layout_height="80dp"
            android:background="@color/someColor"
            android:layout_marginTop="90dp"/>


    </com.pompeiicity.smslibrary.widgets.TouchMovingLayout>
```

Happy coding.

Comment: Yes, as I said, it is very simple. I am a admirer of my codes, I always make codes simple, so that I never have to write code comments. Good codes are the code comments.

Answer (score 1):

```
public class Main extends Activity {


private int mCurrentX;
private int mCurrentY;
private View popUpView;
private Button button1;
private TextView textview1;
private PopupWindow popUpWindow;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);

    popUpView = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.layout1, null);        
    button1 = (Button)popUpView.findViewById(R.id.button1);
    textview1 = (TextView)popUpView.findViewById(R.id.textview1);

    popUpWindow = new PopupWindow(popUpView, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
    popUpWindow.setBackgroundDrawable(new ColorDrawable(Color.TRANSPARENT));
    popUpWindow.setOutsideTouchable(true);
    popUpWindow.update();


    OnTouchListener otl = new OnTouchListener() {
        private float mDx;
        private float mDy;          
        @Override
        public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {

            int action = event.getAction();
            if(action==MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN){
                mDx = mCurrentX - event.getRawX();
                mDy = mCurrentY - event.getRawY();                  
            }else if(action== MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE){
                mCurrentX = (int) (event.getRawX()+mDx);
                mCurrentY = (int) (event.getRawY()+mDy);
                popUpWindow.update(mCurrentX, mCurrentY,-1 ,-1);                    
            }

            return true;                
        }
    };
    popUpView.setOnTouchListener(otl);
    mCurrentX = 20;
    mCurrentY = 50;
    popUpView.post(new Runnable() {         
        @Override
        public void run() {
            popUpWindow.showAtLocation(popUpView, Gravity.NO_GRAVITY, mCurrentX, mCurrentY);
            popUpWindow.update();
        }
    });
}
```

}

Comment: thank you for your answer! can you implement a zoom function too?

Comment: you can use `popUpWindow.setHeight(Height);` and `popUpWindow.setWidth(Width);` to change popUpWindow size